# Labelling the vertices in AxisHelper of THREE.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

Consider the code below:

```
<html>   
    <head>  
        <title>My first Three.js app</title>  
        <style>canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }</style>  
    </head>  
<body>  
        <script src="https://rawgithub.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js">  </script>  
        <script>        
      var scene=new THREE.Scene();
      var axis;   
      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);  
      camera.position.z = 3;          
      var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
      renderer.setSize(document.body.clientWidth,document.body.clientHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement); 
      renderer.setClearColorHex(0xEEEEEE, 1.0);
      renderer.clear();
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry(50,50,50),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000}));        
        scene.add( cube );  
         function animate(t) {      
        camera.position.x = Math.sin(t/1000)*300;
        camera.position.y = 150;
        camera.position.z = Math.cos(t/1000)*300;      
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);       
        renderer.render(scene, camera);       
        renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(animate, renderer.domElement);// auto called - many advantages
      };
    animate(new Date().getTime());
    axis = new THREE.AxisHelper(75);
    scene.add(axis);      
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code creates x,y,z axis in the cube.
Kindly help me to label the axis.
The Labelled text must rotate along with the axis.
I need a sample code to customize the axis helper(to create labels) in THREE.js

Comment: So far what steps have you tried to achieve your goal? I just see you've added the `AxisHelper`. Have you tried `TextGeometry`, and positioning it at the end of each line? Perhaps setting the TextGeomety.lookAt to the camera object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text geometry can be added as below:

```
var  textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry('Y', {
     size: 5,
     height: 2,
     curveSegments: 6,
     font: "helvetiker",
     style: "normal"       
});

var  color = new THREE.Color();
color.setRGB(255, 250, 250);
var  textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: color });
var  text = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo , textMaterial);

text.position.x = axis.geometry.vertices[1].x;
text.position.y = axis.geometry.vertices[1].y;
text.position.z = axis.geometry.vertices[1].z;
text.rotation = camera.rotation;
scene.add(text);
```

You need to include `helvetiker_regular.typeface.js` font file before using `TextGeometry` as Three,js needs it for loading `THREE.TextGeometry`. You can add other labels just either by creating clones of mesh object or creating new text geometries and changing the xyz position as per vertices[3] and vertices[5] of axis helper.

Comment: `typeface-0.15.js` must be included before threejs, `helvetiker_regular.typeface.js` must be included after.  This is because threejs monkeypatches the typeface loader. :-/

Comment: Here is the solution that worked for me for adding text: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589984/textgeometry-in-three-js

Answer (score 11):

FWIW, there seems to be a pattern in three.js (and blender, for that matter), where the x, y, z axis are red, green, and blue, respectively (i.e., RGB), so if you can match RGB with XYZ, it can aid in determining which axis is which.