# TextGeometry in Three.js

Tags: three.js, geometry

I am having some problems with the TextGeometry in Three.js r74..

How do I implement it correctly?

Here is my Codepen:

```
codepen.io/cheesyeyes/pen/eJqZxK
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_text.html

Comment: Here is another example. http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shadowmap.html

Answer (score 17):

Okey, for everyone who is looking for simple answers and not links and links to other overloaded examples:

fonts have to be loaded with the three js FontLoader first:

```
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load( 'fonts/fontname.js', function ( font ) {

  var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( "text", {

    font: font,

    size: 50,
    height: 10,
    curveSegments: 12,

    bevelThickness: 1,
    bevelSize: 1,
    bevelEnabled: true

  });

  var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( 
    { color: 0xff0000, specular: 0xffffff }
  );

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeometry, textMaterial );

  scene.add( mesh );

});
```

Comment: THREE.FontLoader is not a constructor

Comment: I'm getting the "not a constructor" error too, revision 80.

Comment: I dont know what happened in rev 80 but in 81 its defenitely part of the core and must not be loaded separately. so it must be there?

Comment: `FontLoader` is a part of the core since r74

Comment: is it possible to add letter spacing in textgeometry

Comment: This will melt your computer CPU and is now deprecated; searching for new answers...

Answer (score 2):

I will also add that you can convert any existing OTF or TTF font to a JSON or JS font via [TypeFace.js](http://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/), this is necessary for the FontLoader to be able to load it.