# Add labels to AxisHelper - can't get vertices of extremities

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to add labels on AxisHelper which rotates with it. From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564051/labelling-the-vertices-in-axishelper-of-three-js), I used this snippet code :

```
  // Axes
  axes2 = new THREE.AxisHelper(70);

  // Axes labels
  addLabelAxes();
   
  // Add axes to zoomScene
  zoomScene.add(axes2);


function addLabelAxes() {

  // Axes label
  var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
  loader.load( 'js/helvetiker_regular.typeface.js', function ( font ) {

  textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'Example label', {
    font: font,
    size: 15,
        height: 5,
    curveSegments: 10,
    } );
  
  var  color = new THREE.Color();
  color.setRGB(255, 0, 0);
  textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: color });
  meshText = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo, textMaterial);

  // Position of first axis
  meshText.position.x = axes2.geometry.vertices[1].x;
  meshText.position.y = axes2.geometry.vertices[1].y;
  meshText.position.z = axes2.geometry.vertices[1].z;
  
  meshText.rotation = zoomCamera.rotation;
  zoomScene.add(meshText);
  
  });
```

But I get the following error into console log :

```
TypeError: axes2.geometry.vertices is undefined
addLabelAxes/<()
 sphere_dev.js:230
THREE.FontLoader.prototype.load/<()
 three.min.js:382
THREE.XHRLoader.prototype.load/<()
```

What might be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geometry of `AxisHelper`is of type `BufferGeometry`, not of type `Geometry`.

You can access the position elements of the `AxisHelper`'s geometry like so:

```
var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper( 20 );

var position = axes.geometry.attributes.position;
```

`position` is a `BufferAttribute`. If you study its contents, the structure should be obvious.

You then can access the elements of the attribute using a pattern like this:

```
var x = position.getX( index ); // or getY, getZ
```

three.js r.76