# Label arrows created in ArrowHelper of THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

In this question ([Labelling the vertices in AxisHelper of THREE.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564051/labelling-the-vertices-in-axishelper-of-three-js)) is explained how to label axis created with `THREE.AxisHelper`. I tried to follow the same procedure for `THREE.ArrowHelper` without sucessfull. So, I'd like to know how to label the arrows I created, just like when indicating the labels of a coordinate system (x,y,z). In this link it how I tried to reproduce the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/g7oqexr8/

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does not work? It does not show up? It crashes? (if so, where???)

**Tip:**
Why don't you add the label object to the created arrow?

instead of:

```
//text.position.x = arrowHelper.geometry.vertices[1].x;
//text.position.y = arrowHelper.geometry.vertices[1].y;
//text.position.z = arrowHelper.geometry.vertices[1].z;
//text.rotation = camera.rotation;
//scene.add(text);
arrowHelper.add(text);
```

This adds to 'text' the position, rotation and scaling from the arrowHelper.

If you want, you can modify afterwards the 'text' rotation, position or scaling.

**EDIT:**
[Documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/TextGeometry) stands:

> TextGeometry uses typeface.json generated fonts. Some existing fonts can be found located in /examples/fonts and must be included in the page.

That's probably why line with:

```
var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry('Y', {size: 5, height: 2, curveSegments: 6,font: "helvetiker",style: "normal"});
```

is crashing.

Comment: If I only create the text as in the code (lines 30-35, http://jsfiddle.net/g7oqexr8/1/), it results in a black page. The same occurs if I follow your tip, after creating the text as I did. That's the problem I'm facing: I'm not able to write a label for the axis.