How to have axes move with cube? (react-three-fiber/ Three.js)
I am using react-three-fiber(built on Three.js) and want to add x,y,z axes to my cube. The issue is that the axes do not move with the cube, they just stay aligned with the page. How do I get the axes to rotate with the cube?
It seems like the axes move when you rotate the scene/camera., however I'm not doing that, I'm just manually rotating the cube though with ref.current.rotation.x etc... is there a way to manually rotate the axes too? OR is there a way to apply the axes directly to the BoxGeometry/cube rather than to the scene?
Also how can I add labels (x,y,z) to the axes?
Thanks! Here's my code:
const Box = (props) => {
    const ref = useRef()
         
    const websocketRef = useRef();
    const connectWebsocket = () => {
      if (!websocketRef.current) {
        socket.addEventListener("message", (ev) => {
          if (ev.data.includes('ahrs_yaw')) {
            setPose(JSON.parse(ev.data.replaceAll("'", '"')))
          }
        });
        websocketRef.current = socket;
      }
    };
    connectWebsocket();

        useFrame(() => {
            ref.current.rotation.x += .005
            ref.current.rotation.y += .005
            ref.current.rotation.z += .005
        })

        return (
          <mesh
            {...props}
            ref={ref}
            >
            <boxGeometry args={[3, 3, 3]} />
            <meshStandardMaterial color={'orange'} />
          </mesh>
        )
      }

<Canvas>
          <ambientLight intensity={Math.PI / 2} />
          <spotLight position={[10, 10, 10]} angle={0.15} penumbra={1} decay={0} intensity={Math.PI} />
          <pointLight position={[-10, -10, -10]} decay={0} intensity={Math.PI} />
          <Box position={[0, 0, 0] } rotation={[0,0,0]}/>
          <axesHelper args={[5, 5, 5]} />
        </Canvas>

Also how can I add labels to the axes (x, y, z) that move with the cube?
Here's my code for the text
import { extend, Object3DNode } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { FontLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js'
import { TextGeometry } from 'three/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry.js'
import helvetiker from "three/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json"

extend({ TextGeometry })

const helvetikerRegular = new FontLoader().parse(helvetiker)
console.log('helvetiker regular ->', helvetikerRegular)

const textOptions = {
  font: helvetikerRegular,
  size: .4,
  depth: .2,
}

function Text() {
  const font = new FontLoader().parse(helvetiker)
  
  return(
  <mesh position={[0,10,0]}>
      <textGeometry attach='geometry' args={["three.js", textOptions]}/>
      <meshStandardMaterial attach='material' color={'blue'}/>
  </mesh>
  )
}


If you want to add AxesHelper to a mesh, just just do this:
<mesh {...props} ref={ref}>
    <axesHelper/>
    <boxGeometry args={[3, 3, 3]} />
    <meshStandardMaterial color={"orange"} />
</mesh>


thanks so much for the help! Do you know how I can add labels to the axes (x,y,z)? I tried following the example from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564051/labelling-the-vertices-in-axishelper-of-three-js but that was written for Three.js and not react-three-fiber.
I've managed to create TextGeometry in react-three-fiber but not sure how to position it on the axes and have it move with the cube. I added my new code in the original post. Thanks!!
